# Swift: What's wrong with this math function?

Tags: swift, math, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to create a variable with this Unixtime value but has `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error. I really don't know why!

```
func Unixtime()->Int {
    return Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
}
print((Unixtime()+2)*2)
```

It works on the Playground but failed to run if i put it in any project!
What's wrong?

Comment: @BryanChen EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of `Int` is 32-bit on 32-bit platforms (e.g. iPhone 5 and below), but the timestamp nowadays is in the range `0x57300000`, which will certainly overflow when you multiply it by 2. In Swift arithmetic overflow will cause the program to crash.

You could force the output to be an Int64, or just return a `TimeInterval` (a `Double`) if you don't require the output to be an integer.

```
// swift 3
func Unixtime() -> TimeInterval {
    return Date().timeIntervalSince1970
}

// swift 2
func Unixtime() -> NSTimeInterval {
    return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
}

print((Unixtime() + 2) * 2)
```

Comment: So if i run my code on iPhone 6, it will be ok? But failed to execute in iPhone 5?

Comment: @TomSawyer It will not crash but your code is not OK it will be crash on 32-bit platform. You shouldn't rely on the exact size of an Int. If you really want the code to work, use an Int64 or just don't force it to be an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of integer overflow

The result value is something near `2926042746` where as `Int32.max` is `2147483647`. So if you run this in 32bit app, it will overflow and resulting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

The solution is use `UInt64` or `Double`

---

This is the code that reliably reproduce this error

```
func Unixtime()->Int32 {
    return (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
}
print((Unixtime()+2)*2)
```